Socket Connection for MS Teams Bots Using the Bot Framework SDK?
The BotBuilder-Samples repository has a host of sample bots that can be served as async web apps (using aiohttp). I was wondering though, is it possible to simply create something like a socket connection for the bot?
This is possible when developing bots for Slack. The code would look something like the following:
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.socket_mode import SocketModeClient

socket_mode_client = SocketModeClient(
            # This app-level token will be used only for establishing a connection
            app_token=self.connection_args['app_token'],  # xapp-A111-222-xyz
            # You will be using this WebClient for performing Web API calls in listeners
            web_client=WebClient(token='<SLACK-TOKEN>'),  # xoxb-111-222-xyz
        )



socket_mode_client.socket_mode_request_listeners.append(_process_websocket_message)
socket_mode_client.connect()

A more concrete example is available here.
How can I do something similar when deploying a bot for MS Teams? Let's say I want to deploy this simple bot from the above repository:
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, MessageFactory, TurnContext
from botbuilder.schema import ChannelAccount


class EchoBot(ActivityHandler):
    async def on_members_added_activity(
        self, members_added: [ChannelAccount], turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
        for member in members_added:
            if member.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
                await turn_context.send_activity("Hello and welcome!")

    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        return await turn_context.send_activity(
            MessageFactory.text(f"Echo: {turn_context.activity.text}")
        )

In essence, I don't want to create a separate web app for the bot. I want to incorporate it into an existing app that I already have and have it run as a separate thread, for example.
I am open to other approaches as well.

This is not currently supported for Teams channel.  To better achieve your requirements, we recommend submitting this feature request through the Teams Feedback Portal.
